# Memoir: Margins vs Marginsandblock

Tags: memoir, document-classes

I am using [Memoir](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) and try to setting up the pagelayout but it don't matter how often I read section 2.4.2 I don't really get what is the difference between using

```
\setlrmargins{spine}{edge}{ratio}
```

and

```
\setlrmarginsandblock{spine}{edge}{ratio}
```

Can anyone explain in simple words what the excat difference is?

In my institue I have just the requirements of using this:

- up marign: 2-3cm
- down margin: 2-3cm
- inner margin: 3-4cm
- outer margin: 2-3cm

I just use oneside instead of twosided.

Edit: There is a good exmaple an pages 10-11 in the manual of the pagelayout and its features, however for me this is more confusing than helping

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the manual (section 2.4.2):

`\setlrmargins` sets the left and right margins, *assuming that both the page width and the typeblock width are already fixed*. That means the space available  for *both margins together* is also fixed, so there are only a few useful combinations of the input parameters, otherwise you are either over-specifying what you want, or your specification is inconsistent with the page and typeblock widths.

`\setlrmarginsandblock` sets the left and right margins *and the typeblock width* assuming that only the page width has already been fixed. Since this option sets three parameters in the page layout not two, more of the possible combinations of parameters make sense.

Tables 2.4 and 2.5 show what this means, for every possible combination of input parameters.

If you want to set both margins to given sizes, then the textblock width can be calculated (as page width - left margin - right margin) so you want to use `\setlrmarginsandblock`.